# SQL server is stuck

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm in front of a problem, and I dont know what is going on. 
I'm using mobile for storing data into a local customer's pc (SQL server).
The communication method is through wi-fi. The problem is that if for some reason I will close the network adapter and re-open it. SQL server it stuck at all.  I can't communicate with the mobile phone again, till I will reset SQL service or I will close and reopen wifi from my mobile phone. Why is this happen? how can I fix that?
Here is my connection string

```
 string connectionString=" Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword";

 using(SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into customers (name) values '"+Text1.Text+"'",connection))
  {
      connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

Sometimes I am getting error index was outside from bound array, but the most time I'm getting the connection timeout

Comment: I mean just because Xamarin includes `SqlClient` and you can connect your phone directly to your SQL Server ... doesn't mean you should.

Comment: `Insert into customers Text1.Text` This ... is not going to work. You'd want a parameter whose value is `Text1.Text`.

Comment: Ok i corrected in my example. Dont stay there that's not the point

Comment: Imagine in my customer if for some reason will happen this. What should i answer him? It is normal? Make restart your pc? I need an answer

Comment: Make a web service for your app to communicate with. Make the webservice do the sql insert etc

Comment: "*Sometimes I am getting error index was outside from bound array, but the most time I'm getting the connection timeout*" you are having 2 completely different problems here and it makes it really hard to help you. However you will probably find when you are timing-out your sever isn't at `myServerAddress` . the biggest problem here is you really using the wrong technology for the wrong job and it will be unreliable. However on saying, if you really want to hit DB from a phone, the first test id be doing is making sure you can actually contact that address and your ips are not changing

Comment: Does make sense that i must close mobile wifi and re open it for manage to connect again?

Comment: What doesn't make any sense is that you talk about an *index out of bounds of the array* where there isn't any array in your code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the underlying socket communication of SQL Server and you can't fix it.
As @ta.speot.is say, your design absolutely is bad. you can increase the timeout of connection to SQL Server but it's not good solution for bad design. the socket communication is alive. It's like that you unplug the network socket from Server and after connecting it again expecting all the operation resume without any problem!
The sockets is open and depending on the architecture of underlying SQL Server it take some time to sockets close, timeout or etc.

The best solution is to implement a service which communicate with your database, by this way when the WIFI connection lose or something like this happen the underlying connection to database still alive and handled successfully by the web service. your mobile application just get and post requests to web service and don't care about how service handle database operations.

Comment: If will create an http server for this job, it will be faster than  communication directly with sql server(as i work it till now)?

Comment: It depends on your design and select the right tools for implementation. in general, yes the performance is good enough.

Comment: Http server it will be example an exe in my local client's pc, which it will take requests and then it will insert into my local sql server?

Comment: In your case it's a web service that can be implemented using .Net core and run in machine that your SQL Server is there. you don't open any connection directly to SQL Server from network, all requests (insert,update,delete,select and etc) should be handled by your service. in network you just send and receive requests to your service not directly the database.

Comment: I just find that has too much work... Till now i was open a query and  insert or update was made derectly in sql server. Now i need to create an extra application for this job. I dont have any problems till now with my method. But sometimes i am in face the problem i was described for

Comment: @Dhi yes, changing production software is time consuming task, sometimes your program work for long running time(month and years...) but the bad architecture still there and some day for some reasons the feature become to a bug! This is a task you must do it, so eat that frog !

Comment: Thank you i will try it!